# Homebrew install specific minor php version

Tags: php, homebrew, versioning

When installing `brew install php@8.1` it automatically installs latest version 8.1.15. Due to the development purposes I need to install another minor version (e.g. 8.1.7). Since minor versions are hardcoded in formulas, it's not possible to install specific minor version out of the box. What is the easiest way to use an old formula if I could find it in the repo's commit history? I tried this as was advised in different SO thread:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/83b80f3b76c9cbd79e914f927a45a083b1d047e1/Formula/php.rb
```

But it literally won't let me to:

```
Error: Installation of php from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract php` to a stable tap on GitHub instead.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do hack of resetting the commit to [this one](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/188c1842bc571a8f7717027a790ebb1c6e9d5c8d).

Like the option 3 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/791609).